# how give user based permissions for menu items?

Tags: users, navigation, taxonomy-terms

i have 4 parent menu items for this i'm using superfish menu, how to give user based permissions to add a new page for particular parent menu only, 
example: menu item1(userrole1) --> for this userrole1 has to add new pages under menu item1 only, like this i need to add role based menu items, please help me out. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set role-based permissions (/admin/people/permissions) per content type.

Then create Contenttype1 (/admin/structure/types/add) and Userrole1 (/admin/people/roles) and create a Views page for Contenttype1. Then set the page to be displayed under Menuitem1 in your menu settings (/admin/structure/menu).

Comment: i have created a content type and kept menu settings as --Default parent item- when i create a new content type it's not generating a link/new page... please help me out.

Comment: Did you create a View per content type as I suggested? If so enter each View's path as the destination of the relevant menu item.

Comment: yes i have created view per content type but i want automatically add to mainmenu, here im not able to see provide a page link option

Comment: Do you want each post in the content type as a sub item in the menu? Or do you want the menu item to direct to a page with all the posts?

Comment: yes i want each contenttype as submenu for the selected parent menu which is selected on creation of new content type.